# Netty message framing for data frames

Tags: websocket, netty, fragmentation

I am implementing a very simple websocket server using Netty (v4).
I am basing my code on the websocket example source code that comes with Netty.
Do I need to do anything extra to handle framing/fragmentation/packet boundaries?
Or can I assume that the example code reassembles the data correctly?

The example uses calls like:

*String request = ((TextWebSocketFrame) frame).text();*

or:

*ctx.channel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame(request.toUpperCase()));*

So it doesn't seem to be dealing with fragmentation (at that layer at least).
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The frames are handled as complete frames. If you need to aggregate also ContinumWebSocketFrames you can put WebSocketFrameAggregator in the ChannelPipeline.

Comment: Does the WebSocketFrameAggregator also aggregate outgoing frames? I know the HttpObjectAggregator does, but can't for the life of me work out how!

Comment: Both only aggregate inbound frames.

Comment: Aaaaaah I finally get it. HttpObjectAggregator only affects requests on server and responses on client! Thanks so much for reply.